# How to print a for loop as a list

Tags: python, for-loop

So I have:

```
s = (4,8,9), (1,2,3), (4,5,6)
for i, (a,b,c) in enumerate(s):
    k = [a,b,c]  
    e = k[0]+k[1]+k[2]
    print e
```

It would print:

```
21
6
15
```

But I want it to be:

```
(21,6,15)
```

I tried using this but it's not what I wanted:

```
print i,
```

So is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are a few options:

- Using tuple unpacking and a generator:

  ```
  print tuple(a+b+c for a, b, c in s)
  ```
- Using `sum()` and a generator:

  ```
  print tuple(sum(t) for t in s)
  ```
- Using `map()`:

  ```
  print tuple(map(sum, s))
  ```

Comment: Of the 3 options you have here, I like the second one best.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = (4,8,9), (1,2,3), (4,5,6)
print tuple([sum(x) for x in s])
```

Comment: Note that the list comprehension could be turned into a generator expression by removing the `[]`.  It doesn't make much of a difference here, but there are other circumstances where it could be significant in terms of memory usage and performance.

Comment: Don't look at me -- I didn't do it :)

Answer (score 0):

`print` always prints a new line. If you want to print one line, you need to do your printing all at once.

Inside your loop, create a string, and print that. Or, given how you want it formatted, you could also create a tuple (which is represented with round brackets, as you have).

Incidentally, if you want to add the members of a list, you can just use `sum`:

```
e = sum(k)
```

Also, `s` is already a tuple, you don't need to enumerate it - you can just loop over it with:

```
for k in s:
    e = sum(k)
```

Now, go ahead and put that all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l = []
>>> for i, (a,b,c) in enumerate(s):
...     k = [a,b,c]  
...     e = k[0]+k[1]+k[2]
...     l.append(e)
... 
>>> print l
[21, 6, 15]
```

I do hope this helps. You're appending the sum of list k to list l and finally printing it out.

Comment: Why create an intermediate list just to pull out the indices?  you could do `for i,k in enumerate(s):` just as easily here.

Comment: Thanks this works when `s` is that length but when I tried it with a longer length, it doesn't seem to work...